# Eurobraille in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, accessibility, braille

I want to use *eurobraille* (also known as *8 point braille* or *computer braille*) in LaTeX. I am aware of the [braille package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/braille/braille.html), but it does not support *eurobraille*.

Comment: I just found this eurobraille font: http://www.fakoo.de/braille-fonts/#achtpunkt. I currently have trouble installing it, but that is probably subject for another question.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using a braille font from here: http://www.fakoo.de/braille-fonts/#achtpunkt

With xelatex it was no problem to use this font for the parts of the document, where I wanted braille.